# "Position: Contain" in AMP Carousel

Tags: carousel, amp-html

When creating an AMP Carousel, how do I make sure that pictures with different proportions stay contained in the same way? In other words, the pictures will display width: 100%, but the height will be cut in relation to the proportion of the picture.

Comment: Use fixed-height layout for carousel and image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this combining a `fixed-height` layout for the `amp-carousel` with a `fill` layout for the `amp-img`:

```
<amp-carousel height="300"
  layout="fixed-height"
  type="slides">
  <div class="fixed-height-container">
    <amp-img class="contain"
      layout="fill"
      src="https://unsplash.it/500/400"></amp-img>
  </div>
```

The trick is to use `object-fit: contain|cover` for the embedded `img`:

```
.contain img {
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

[Here](https://ampbyexample.com/advanced/how_to_support_images_with_unknown_dimensions/#image-carousels) is a sample.